# Can I set multiple Codeigniter Where criteria from an array?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get data from a database that meets multiple criteria of an array.

The array is something like this:

```
Array ([21] => 1,[23] => 0,[19] => 1);
```

With the key being a Question ID and the values being either yes or no.

I need to find the movie where the value for `question_id = 21` is `1`, value for `question_id = 23` is `0` and value for `question_id = 19` is `1`.  The way I have them stored is like this:

[image]

So my first thought was get the data for each and then put them in a bigger array.  If the movie shows up the same amount of times as the number of elements in the array, then I consider it a good match.  But this seems inefficient.  I would rather just find the movies that match the criteria.

Since there are `movie_id` records with the same value, is there a way to write something like this?:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
$i++;
$this->db->where('question_id', $key);
$this->db->where('value', $value);

}
$this->db->from('movies_values');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $res = $query->result();
    array_push($main,$res);
```

The thought behind this is to create a loop of all the `WHERE`s.  And then run the query using those where values.  This doesn't seem to work, is there something else I can do?

Comment: Off-topic: phpMyAdmin has improved a lot since that screenshot you posted. Consider upgrading ;)

Comment: ok will do - - 123456

Comment: Also, I'd be willing to bet there's a great way to do this in pure SQL... no PHP needed.

Answer (score 1):

How about using WHERE IN (array())?

From the [CI User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html):

```
$names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');
$this->db->where_in('username', $names);
// Produces: WHERE username IN ('Frank', 'Todd', 'James')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `where_in` method for lists:

```
$this->db->where_in('value', $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this.

```
$where = WHERE 1
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
   $where .= " AND(question_id = $key AND value = $value)";
}

$this->db->where($where);
```

PS. What is the $i++ doing in your loop exactly?

Comment: Would the fact that this would be looking for a single record matter? What I mean is, the way I set it up (as seen in the above picture) is that I have many different records for the same movie.  When I run this, how would I be able to extract the movie even though it is checking different records?  Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Also, what does WHERE 1 mean?

Comment: For your first question the movie id would be available in the return $query no? WHERE 1 just gives you a starting point to build the $where variable, it means return everything basically, then the foreach would build the filters off of that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the right way to go, you should take care to use "or" instead to use full "ands" that way would not return any row due to a logic problem  (I mean question_id = 1 and value = 1 and question_id = 2 and value = 0 we're being inconsistent due to telling that we want question_id = 1 and question_id = 2 won't match nothing!, the same applies to "values").

```
        $array = array(21 => 1,23 => 0,19 => 1);
        $where = array();
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            $where[] = "(question_id=$key and value=$value)";
        }
        var_dump($where);
        foreach ($where as $value) {
            $this->db->or_where($value);
        }
        $q = $this->db->get('movies_values')->result();
        var_dump($q);
        echo $this->db->last_query();exit;
```

Comment: I've already seen that this can be done in just one foreach, so for best visibility I did it that way ,but you can do `$this->db->or_where("(question_id=$key and value=$value)");` at the first foreach avoiding the second.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily without loop:

```
$filter = array(21 => 1,23 => 0,19 => 1);

$values = implode(',',array_unique(array_values($filter))); // results into 0,1...
$keys   = implode(',',array_unique(array_keys($filter))); // results into 19,21,23...

$result = $this->db
              ->query("select * from movies_values
                         where 
                            question_id in(".$keys.")
                            and value in(".$values.")")
              ->result();
```

Happy coding ---> :)